# How to add a line to the top of the icon in tab bar react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, styling

I'm using https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html for doing tab bars and so far its working fine.

How can I add a line on top of the tab icon when selected. I can't figure it out as hardcoding values like padding or such will create a different effect on different screens. This is my code:

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: props => (
            <Icon routeName={navigation.state.routeName} {...props} />
        )
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor:'blue',
        inactiveTintColor: "white",
        style: {
            backgroundColor:'grey'
        }
    }
```

My Icon component is:

```
<Image source={focused ? require('icon.png') : require('icon-selected.png')} style={{ tintColor: focused ? 'blue' : 'white', padding: focused ? 0 : 4 }}
        />
```

The above works fine except how do I add a line above every tab icon once selected.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a view above the icon,then use sth in the state as a flag when selcted the flag turns into true then the line added to the above else nothing happens